# How to create a React app directly in the current folder

Tags: reactjs, command-line, create-react-app

I know I've done it before but I can't seem to find the answer anywhere. I want to run create-react-app without creating a whole other folder within the folder I'm already in. I believe it is just an additional flag appended to the command.

Comment: Before adding another answer, please note that `create-react-app .` and `npx create-react-app .` have been more than adequately covered by existing answers. Please make sure that your answer adds something new.

Answer (score 431, accepted):

You can create a new React app in the current directory by writing `.` instead of a project name.

```
create-react-app .
```

Comment: This was working before, but now for some reason it gives me an error saying `name can only contain URL-friendly characters` `* name can no longer contain capital letters` `Please choose a different project name.`

Comment: @ZeyadShaban Your current directory name probably contains capital letters. Try renaming it to only have lowercase letters.

Answer (score 118):

> If you've previously installed `create-react-app` globally via `npm install -g create-react-app`, we recommend you uninstall the package using `npm uninstall -g create-react-app` to ensure that `npx` always uses the latest version.

For a new version of `create-react-app` (v3):

```
npx create-react-app .
```

Please pay attention to *a full stop*(dot) at the end of your command `.` which corresponds to a current directory

Comment: This should have been accepted answer as it's clearly explained what exactly needs to be done

Comment: @vikramvi, maybe in some cases. Not everyone would have install create-react-app globally before. In my case for example I needed to change the name of the current directoy as stated below https://stackoverflow.com/a/60487093/9208887

Comment: @TheFool that's the whole point of using npx.  You don't need to have it installed globally.

Comment: Yes, still someone is saying accepted answer should be related to global install or not? One  has also nothing to do with the other. Just because you run some npx command doesn't mean it hasn't been installed in your system before. Just in my case it hasnt.

Comment: This is saying "The directory . contains files that could conflict: <all files in the current folder>"

Answer (score 26):

The following works *only* if your current directory complies with npm naming restrictions.

```
npx create-react-app .
```

The current directory must:

- contain only URL friendly characters
- no capital letters

E.g., current directory cannot be named "React App". It must be "react-app".

Comment: This is really interesting. Why can I create a react project with a capital letter when I'm giving the normal command (npx create-react-app Name-Project)?

Comment: @timman NTFS and FAT filesystems are case-insensitive.

Answer (score 19):

In my case, I was using Windows PowerShell and `npx create-react-app ./` didn't work for me, so I ended up using this instead -

```sh
npx create-react-app .
```

Answer (score 10):

```
npx create-react-app . my-app --template typescript
```

Comment: This question already has a lot of answers. Can you explain how yours improves on what's already here?

Answer (score 5):

First, go to the directory where you want to create react app.

Then run the command `npx create-react-app .`

I am simply putting a dot(.) instead of the project name.

Answer (score 4):

Creating a text project in the current directory you're in is as simple as running the below command.

```
npx create-react-app .
```

Or this when you have create react app installed globally.

```
 create-react-app .
```

One important thing i want you to notice is the full stop (or period or dot) at the end of every command. That full stop indicates that you want to create the  app in the current folder.

I hope this helps

Answer (score 4):

You simple type . instead of react-app-name

```
npx create-react-app .
```

If you have already had any folder name which starts with . then you will get an error.
You need to remove the folder and then try above command

Answer (score 3):

When you use `create-react-app app-name`, the part that comes after `create-react-app` tells CRA ***where*** to create a react app. So `create-react-app app-name` is actually telling CRA to create a react app in a new directory called 'my-app'. This can cause lots of issues with deployment for the inexperienced developer.

By using `npx create-react-app .` we can tell CRA to create a react app *here* or in the current directory. This will help prevent any issues which may come from not having your react app directly in the root directory of your project or repo.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a new React app in the current directory by writing ./ instead of a project name.

Run that command in Your terminal>
`npx create-react-app ./`

ex.-

`PS E:\React Course\covid-19-state-vice-cases>npx create-react-app ./`

Answer (score 2):

This works for me.

`npx create-react-app .`

1. First go to the directory where you want to create react app.
2. Then run the command `npx create-react-app .`

- simply putting a dot(.) instead of project name.

N.B:
If you install `create-react-app` package directly via npm by this command `npm install create-react-app`, then you have to run the following command to create react app in current directory `create-react-app .` (no need to add npx then).

Answer (score 0):

create-react-app .

I've found this very useful for separating my client and server into individual directories underneath a parent project directory. This way you can keep your server and client seperate and easily know which API's are working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

react-app .` will work but remember due to their naming restrictions you cannot have the first letter capital so remember to change the folder name to lower case before adding that

Answer (score 0):

*create-react-app .

I know I've done it before but I can't seem to find the answer anywhere. I want to run create-react-app without creating a whole other folder within the folder I'm already in. I believe it is just an additional flag appended to the command.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Open the folder -> go to the terminal and Write:- `npx create-react-app "your app name"` Example:

```
npx create-react-app xyz
```

press enter. This will automatically create the new app.

Answer (score -12):

if your are using the latest version of **Nodejs** so you can use this code:

```
npx create-react-app your-app-name
```

you check Node version by this code:

```
node --version
```

it shall be above v10

Comment: The question clearly mentioned "create project directly in the current folder" and the answer provided will create the project within another directory.