# npx packages are not installing in my Project folder

Tags: reactjs, npx

I have used npx create-react-app my-app command in vsstudio and have created my project in E:\ directory but after running the command npx is installing the packages in C:.

Below are the terminal lines(in VSCode):

```
PS E:\Web Development 2022\reactjs> npx create-react-app my-app

Creating a new React app in C:\Users\dell\Desktop\my-app.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...
```

Can anyone help me how to make npx install things in the same directory in which I am creating a project?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a React app directly in the current folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55082584/how-to-create-a-react-app-directly-in-the-current-folder)

Comment: @HereticMonkey No!. actually in VScode its creating the app by default in C:\Users\dell\Desktop\my-app. and i am creating the app in E: folder.

Comment: You can refer the lines shown in my Terminal.

Comment: Try running `npx create-react-app .` from your VSCode terminal, as it says in the answers to that question. Otherwise `npx` uses your home folder, which is apparently set to `C:\Users\dell\Desktop`.

Comment: @HereticMonkey have tried npx create-react-app .  also but its still creating my-app on Desktop. Is there a way i can change some settings so that npx always install in my Project folder only?