# How can I solve the "Module Not Found" problem when I run "npm start" after create a react project with npm?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, yarn-v2

I'm new in React.js & npm.

Firstly, I use the command

`npm create react-app my-test-npm-react-app`

Then I waited for a while. It helped me create a react project. Everything looks normal. But when I run

`npm start`

The command prompt:

```
> my-test-npm-react-app@0.1.0 start
> react-scripts start

'Projects\my-test-npm-react-app\node_modules\.bin\' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or a batch file.
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'D:\00Fronted-End-WebDev\Study Codes\07. React.js\react-scripts\bin\react-scripts.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

It worked normal when I used yarn. But npm not!

How can I solve this? (I have already tried some methods but it didn't work)

I did this:

1. delete the `package-lock.json` and `node_modules`
2. run command `npm install` to reinstall the packages
3. then run `npm start` but it still didn't work normal

Why?

Comment: Without using `.` at the end of the command the project is not created inside your directory. `cd my-test-npm-react-app; npm start`

Comment: Thank you, Aleksandar. But `npm start` is running in the directory "my-test-npm-react-app". And you said "Without using . at the end of the command", Do you mean that I should use `npm create react-app my-test-npm-react-app.` rather than `npm create react-app my-test-npm-react-app`?

Comment: No, exchange the app-name for . ex.: `npm create react-app .` if the directory is empty will create the app inside your current directory, otherwise throws error, but even then you shouldn't use `npm` but `npx`: [`npx create-react-app .`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69233517/12737879). When you use an app-name instead, it creates a folder with the app-name that you should `cd` into.

Comment: I just tried this. I made a new directory "test-dir" and run `npm create react-app .`

then the "test-dir" directory was filled with react project files. And I run `npm start`. Still this problem. 

When I use `yarn create react-app my-app`, `yarn start`, it works well. I don't know why npm is not.

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete your node_modules and package-lock.json (not package.json) files, re-run `npm install` and restart your IDE.

> If you are on macOS or Linux, issue the following commands in `bash` or `zsh`.

```
shell
# for macOS or Linux
rm -rf node_modules
rm -f package-lock.json
rm -f yarn.lock

# ️ clean npm cache
npm cache clean --force

# ️ install packages
npm install
```

> If you are on Windows, issue the following commands in CMD.

```
shell

# ️  (Windows) delete node_modules and package-lock.json
rd /s /q "node_modules"
del package-lock.json
del -f yarn.lock

# ️ clean npm cache
npm cache clean --force

# ️ install packages
npm install
```

For more [link](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/javascript-cannot-find-module-loader-js)